# How to detect/control the SoftInputPanel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, soft-input-panel

The `SoftInputPanel`, *Soft Input Panel*, or `SIP` is the *on screen keyboard* that displays on Windows Mobile devices.

How do I detect when someone clicks the `SIP`?

How do I programmatically enable/disable the `SIP`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind.

Found a good article [>> HERE <<](http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/42).

Basically include `using Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms;` and a `P/Invoke`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test1 {

  public class Form1 : Form {

    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    public static extern bool SipShowIM(int dwFlag);

    InputPanel sip;

    public Form1() {
      InitializeComponent();
      sip = new InputPanel();
      sip.EnabledChanged += new EventHandler(SIP_EnabledChanged);
    }

    void SIP_EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if (sip.Enabled) {
        Console.WriteLine("Enabled");
      } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Disabled");
      }
    }

  }

}
```