# Disable the touchpanel on Windows Mobile device

Tags: windows-mobile

I am trying to disable the touch screen on Windows Mobile device.  One way is that if I change the registry DriverName to nothing then warmbooth the device, the touch screen seems to be disabled so I wonder if I use this approach, will I encounter any unknown side affect later?

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\TOUCH]

"DriverName"=""

thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7970556/153923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use TouchRegisterWindow API to 'disable' touch input. See here for an example: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/09/24/windows-mobile-disable-touch-input/

I would no go the way you described but just use the TouchRegisterWindow API. It is simple and clean.